# convert this code to a version without "async - await"

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I'm trying to convert this code to a version without "async - await". Code converted to use (all) promises without async and await. But my console print undefined for time. Can someone help me? Its for a homework of my College.
Thanks very much

```
(async() => {

  function exibirErro(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }

  const f1 = async(tempo) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const f = () => reject(new Error('Rejeitado'));
      console.log(`Aguardando ${tempo} segundos...`);
      setTimeout(f, tempo);
    });
  };

  const f2 = async(x) => {
    if ((Math.random() * 10) % 2 == 0) {
      throw new Error('Ops');
    }
    return Promise.resolve(1000 * x);
  };

  const f3 = async() => {
    const r = await new Promise(resolve => resolve(2));
    const t = await f2(r);
    await f1(t);
  };

  try {
    await f3();
  } catch (err) {
    exibirErro(err);
  }

})();
```

My code:

```
function exibirErro(err) {
  console.log(err.message);
}

function f1(tempo) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const f = () => reject(new Error('Reject'));
      console.log(`wait ${tempo} seconds...`);
      setTimeout(f, tempo);
    })
    .then((x) => {
      if ((Math.random() * 10) % 2 == 0) {
        throw new Error('Ops');
      }
      return Promise.resolve(1000 * x);
    })
    .then((t) => {
      return Promisse.resolve(f1(t));
    }).catch((e) => {
      exibirErro(e);
    })
}

f1();
```

Comment: Why are you returning a promise in an `async` function? It returns a promise automatically, so you're returning a promise in a promise.

Comment: `Math.random() * 10) % 2 == 0` tests if a random floating point number in the range [0,10] is an exact integer, and even as well. That has such a low probability that I would not expect it to happen during thousands of tests or more.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with your wrapper function -

```
(async() => {
```

First we have a normal synchronous function, nothing to change here -

```
  function exibirErro(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
```

Next we have function `f1` which uses the `async` keyword but does not `await` anything. All you have to do here is remove the `async` keyword -

```
  const f1 = async(tempo) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const f = () => reject(new Error('Rejeitado'));
      console.log(`Aguardando ${tempo} segundos...`);
      setTimeout(f, tempo);
    });
  };
```

Next we have function `f2`, which again uses `async` but does not `await` anything. Simply remove `async` -

```js
  const f2 = async(x) => {
    if ((Math.random() * 10) % 2 == 0) {
      throw new Error('Ops');
    }
    return Promise.resolve(1000 * x);
  };
```

Then we have function `f3` that `await`s two things, `r` and `t` -

```js
  const f3 = async() => {
    const r = await new Promise(resolve => resolve(2));
    const t = await f2(r);
    await f1(t); // missing return
  };
```

We can rewrite `f3` using `.then` -

```
  const f3 = () =>
    new Promise(resolve => resolve(2)).then(r =>
      f2(r).then(t =>
        f1(t)
      )
    )
```

Finally you have `try`/`catch` -

```js
  try {
    await f3();
  } catch (err) {
    exibirErro(err);
  }
```

Simply use `.catch` instead -

```js
f3().catch(exibirErro)
```

And the closing syntax for the `async` wrapper function. The wrapper will not be needed in the final version.

```
})();
```

Here it is all together now -

```js
function exibirErro(err) {
  console.log(err.message);
}

const f1 = tempo => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const f = () => reject(new Error('Rejeitado'));
    console.log(`Aguardando ${tempo} segundos...`);
    setTimeout(f, tempo);
  });
};

const f2 = x => {
  if ((Math.random() * 10) % 2 == 0) {
    throw new Error('Ops');
  }
  return Promise.resolve(1000 * x);
};

const f3 = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => resolve(2)).then(r =>
    f2(r).then(t =>
      f1(t)
    )
  )
}

f3().catch(exibirErro)
```